# How to add facebook comment to my wordpress blog?

Tags: wordpress, facebook-apps

I have wordpress blog , http://luckyleosan.wordpress.com/2014/03/07/sample-photo/#comments. i wanna  add facebook comment to wordpress blog. how can i do that? i have searched about this in google. but in facebook developer site, its asking the domain name- if i give my above url, its showing the error of url should be canvas url.?

canvas url in facebook means?

what i will do it now?

how to add facebook comment to above url blog?

please help me. am facebook and wordpress newb..

Answer (score 0):

The Facebook site you are looking at is designed for developers looking to build plugins that integrate Facebook with WordPress and other platforms. Hence the registration requirements.

Instead, you can use the official [Facebook plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/facebook/screenshots/) for WordPress. It will replace default WordPress comments with the Facebook comment box. It will also give you some handy features like shortcodes for a like button and open graph meta setup.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Facebook Comments](http://wordpress.org/plugins/facebook-comments-plugin/) Plugin for fb comments.